# How to load a pre-trained PyTorch model?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm following [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html) guide on saving and loading checkpoints. However, something is not right. My model would train and the parameters would correctly update during the training phase. However, there seem to be a problem when I load the checkpoints. That is, the parameters are not being updated anymore.

My model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

PATH = 'test.pt'

class model(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(model, self).__init__()
            self.a = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True))
            self.b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True))
            self.c = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True))
            #print(self.a, self.b, self.c)

        def load(self):
          try:
            checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)  
            print('\nloading pre-trained model...')
            self.a = checkpoint['a']
            self.b = checkpoint['b']
            self.c = checkpoint['c']
            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
            print(self.a, self.b, self.c)
          except: #file doesn't exist yet
            pass

        @property
        def b_opt(self):
            return torch.tanh(self.b)*2

        def train(self):
          print('training...')
          for epoch in range(3):
            print(self.a, self.b, self.c)
            for r in range(5):
              optimizer.zero_grad()
              loss = torch.square(5 * (r > 2) * (3) - model_net.a * torch.sigmoid((r - model_net.b)) * (model_net.c))
              loss.backward(retain_graph=True) #accumulate gradients

            #checkpoint save
            torch.save({
                'model': model_net.state_dict(),
                'a': model_net.a,
                'b': model_net.b,
                'c': model_net.c,
                'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
                }, PATH)

            
            optimizer.step() 
          


model_net = model()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model_net.parameters(), lr = 0.1)


print(model_net.a)
print(model_net.b)
print(model_net.c)
```

This prints

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4214], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3862], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.8812], requires_grad=True)
```

I then run `model_net.train()` to see that the parameters are being updated and this outputs:

```
training...
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.9990], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.1580], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.1517], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.0990], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.0580], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2517], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1974], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0404], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3518], requires_grad=True)
```

Running `model_net.load()` outputs:

```
loading pre-trained model...
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1974], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0404], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3518], requires_grad=True)
```

And lastly, running `model_net.train()` again outputs:

```
training...
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1974], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0404], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3518], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1974], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0404], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3518], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1974], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0404], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3518], requires_grad=True)
```

**Update 1**.
Following @jhso suggestion I changed my load to:

```
def load(self):
  try:
    checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)  
    print('\nloading pre-trained model...')
    self.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
    self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
    print(self.a, self.b, self.c)
  except: #file doesn't exist yet
    pass
```

This almost seems to work (the network is training now), but I don't think the optimizer is loading correctly. That is because it doesn't go pass the line `self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])`.
You can see that since it doesn't `print(self.a, self.b, self.c)` when I run

```
model_net.load()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are loading your data is not the recommended way to load your parameters because you're overwriting the graph connections (or something along those lines...). You even save the model state_dict, so why not use it!

I changed the load function to:

```
def load(self):
      try:
        checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)  
        print('\nloading pre-trained model...')
        self.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
        self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
        print(self.a, self.b, self.c)
        self.train()
      except: #file doesn't exist yet
        pass
```

But note to do this, you have to add your optimizer to your model:

```
model_net = model()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model_net.parameters(), lr = 0.1)
model_net.optimizer = optimizer
```

Which then gave the output (running train, load, train):

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2316], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4561], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.8626], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3316], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.3561], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.9626], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4317], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2568], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([1.0620], requires_grad=True)

loading pre-trained model...
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4317], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2568], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([1.0620], requires_grad=True)
training...
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.4317], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.2568], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([1.0620], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.5321], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.1577], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([1.1612], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([0.6328], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([0.0583], requires_grad=True) Parameter containing:
tensor([1.2606], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Please see my update. This almost seems to work!

Comment: See my note: note I added your optimizer to the class....

Comment: `model_net = model();
optimizer = optim.Adam(model_net.parameters(), lr = 0.1);
model_net.optimizer = optimizer`

Comment: Any chance you can edit and add the complete code to make sure I'm not missing anything?

Comment: Sorry, should've done that in the first place. Done now.

Comment: Perfect! Really appreciate it! Going over it again to make sure everything works but so far I think this is the answer! Going to accept it in a few : )

Comment: Also, I don't really think this is the right way to do this. I think it'd be better to pass the optimizer as an argument to the save/load function rather than make it an attribute of this class.

Comment: What do you mean? I also have a lr scheduler, I suppose I should do the same trick with the `self`?

Comment: I meant in the way I did it. I think it's just better practice to keep your model and optimizer separate. Regardless, the question has been answered (hopefully) :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks : ) And just to verify, I'm supposed to save individual parameters (`self.a`) in the `save` stage, but not call `self.a = checkpoint['a']` in the load stage because it messes up with the computational graph?

Comment: That is my guess.